# Send Input to a File In Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, testing, cross-browser

I want to put the code in the textarea's as below and send it to a file and I do not know Ajax I understand it but can't write.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="html"></textarea>
    <textarea id="js"></textarea>
    <textarea id="css"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" value="Run" id="run">
    <iframe src="example.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <button onclick="loadDoc()">Try The Ajax</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of main.js are:

```
function loadDoc() {
    var fred = document.getElementById("js");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("html").innerHTML =
                this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "example.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

It loads but will not send. I have tried `xhttp.send(fred, "example.html",true)` but it did not work. So abit like [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: do you get any errors? what about if you look at the network tab in you browsers dev console? anything there? Does the server you send the request to work/send data back?

Comment: 1- SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError -main.js (9,4)
ie. just before the bracket

Comment: 2-  SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError -main.js (10,5) ie.http.send("POST", "files/try.html", true);

Comment: Where are you sending the request to? what is `example.html`? it needs to be a valid URL and not the name of a file. Does Quentin's answer below make sense to you?

Comment: it is a valid url

Comment: do you own the server the url points to? or are you using some third party service? If you own the url what does the server expect to receive?

Comment: it is a local file

Comment: The browser cannot alter local files on your operating system due to security concerns. You will need a server running somewhere to do that. Quentin's answer explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is the act of making an HTTP request from JavaScript without leaving the page.

**It cannot write to files.**

You can make an HTTP request to a URL which is handled by server-side code that uses information in the request to write to a file (although it is more usual to write to a database).

Pick a programming language you like and look up an introductory tutorial for server-side programming using it.